# Dynamically binding free identifiers in a function body

Tags: racket

Consider a very simple actor language where an actor defines some local state and some methods that can be invoked by sending messages to the actor. In its implementation, one such method of the actor can be transformed into a function that defines the formal parameters of the method and accepts the current local state of the actor. Calling the method returns the new local state.

Binding the formal parameters in the body is no problem, but binding the local state seems to be more difficult. In the example at the end of the code below, in the body of the `save` method the `a` will remain unbound, despite an `a` (a different `a`) being bound by the generated `evaluate-body` function in the `METHOD` macro. The critical point in the code sample below is thus the `METHOD` macro, more specifically the `evaluate-body` function (which is where binding should happen, implying that my program design is reasonable)

Is there a way to hygienically bind this arbitrary set of free identifiers (currently only containing `a`, but it may be anything, really)?

```
#lang racket

(require (for-syntax syntax/parse))
(require racket/stxparam)

(struct actor (local-state methods))
(struct method (name formal-parameters body))

(define-syntax-parameter local-state-variables #f)

(define-syntax (ACTOR stx)
  (syntax-parse stx
    [(_ (LOCAL_STATE state-variable ...) method:expr ...+)
     #'(syntax-parameterize ([local-state-variables '(state-variable ...)])
         ; For the sake of simplicity, an actor is currently a list of message handlers
         (actor
          (make-list (length '(state-variable ...)) (void))
          (list method ...)))]))


(define-syntax (METHOD stx)
  (syntax-parse stx
    [(_ (name:id formal-parameter:id ...) body:expr ...+)
     (with-syntax ([(local-state-variable ...) (syntax-parameter-value #'local-state-variables)])
       #'(method
          'name
          '(formal-parameter ...)
          (λ (formal-parameter ... #:local-state [current-state '()])
            ; the "a" that will be bound here is different from the free identifier "a" in the body
            (define (evaluate-body local-state-variable ...)
              body ...
              (list local-state-variable ...))
            (apply evaluate-body current-state))))]))


(ACTOR (LOCAL_STATE a)
       (METHOD (save new-a)
               ; "a" is an unbound identifier
               (set! a new-a)))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order for the local state variables to have the proper lexical context, you need to store them as identifiers, not symbols. That is, in the result of the `ACTOR` macro, you need to change the `syntax-parameterize` to this:

```
#'(syntax-parameterize ([local-state-variables #'(state-variable ...)])
    #| rest of the template (unchanged)... |#)
```

Note the replacement of `quote`/`'` with `syntax`/`#'`. This will store the identifiers with their lexical context instead of as symbols.

The next step is to properly introduce them within the `METHOD` macro. To do this, you just need to apply [`syntax-local-introduce`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/stxtrans.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._syntax-local-introduce%29%29) to the value of the syntax parameter, which will add the macro introduction scope to the identifiers. You can also replace `with-syntax` with `syntax-parse`’s `#:with` clause to simplify things slightly, so the overall macro becomes this:

```
(define-syntax (METHOD stx)
  (syntax-parse stx
    [(_ (name:id formal-parameter:id ...) body:expr ...+)
     #:with (local-state-variable ...)
            (syntax-local-introduce (syntax-parameter-value #'local-state-variables))
     #'(method #| rest of the template (unchanged)... |#)]))
```

This will work.

---

The reason `syntax-local-introduce` is needed here might be a little confusing, but the most intuitive way to think about it is by considering the “sets of scopes” hygiene model that Racket currently uses. In order for macro-introduced bindings to not conflict with user-defined bindings, each piece of syntax returned by a syntax transformer has a fresh scope attached to it, a scope that will never be attached to anything written by the user. Of course, some of the syntax in the result *is* syntax provided by the user, so the macroexpander needs to ensure it doesn’t attach the fresh scope to those syntax objects.

It’s not possible, in general, to figure out which syntax objects should be considered provided by the user since macro authors can “bend” hygiene and create new syntax objects from other ones. The solution, fortunately, is simple and elegant: just attach the macro introduction scope to all syntax objects provided by the user *before* handing them off to the macro, then **flip** the scopes on all pieces of syntax in the result. This way, the user-provided syntax objects will not have the macro introduction scope after the flipping occurs.

The `syntax-local-introduce` function lets you flip this special scope manually. In this case, since the value of `local-state-variables` should be treated like an input to the macro, but it isn’t automatically given the macro introduction scope by the macroexpander (since it isn’t a direct input to the macro), you have to add the scope yourself. That way, the macroexpander will remove the scope after the macro is expanded, and the identifier will end up with the proper lexical context.

Comment: That is amazing. By now I am quite familiar with large parts of the macro system (how to use it), but getting a deep understanding of how it all _works_ is still quite difficult. Thank you for this insightful answer!